# Reset an Android Dialog

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, android-dialog

I found plenty of topics on how to save states of a dialog, for instance using Bundle instances.
However, I can't seem to find how to "properly" reset a dialog.

Consider this sample custom dialog (the XML layout carries an EditText with ID "input_text"):

```
public class CustomDialog extends Dialog {
  public CustomDialog (Context context) { super (context); }

  protected onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.input_query);
    EditText txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_text);

    // Consider that I'm declaring here the use of listeners
    // in order to retrieve input text.
  }
}
```

I'm popping up this dialog when a button is clicked in the main Activity. The second time this action occurs, my EditText contains the input from the previous instance.

Now, I know I can reset the content of this EditText, but I'm wondering if there is a common, already existant method to do this, dialog-wide. For instance if I have a more complex dialog, I want that it has "default" values each time this object is instantiated. I thought removing the call to`super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` could do the trick, but it does not.

Sorry if this is a silly question (or if already addressed... I did not find it)... Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally you should override `onCreateDialog` and `onPrepareDialog` methods of the activity.

For the first time creation of dialogs, `onCreateDialog` is called, so you should create your dialog in this method. To initialize/update the contents of dialogs override `onPrepareDialog`, it is always called before showing a dialog.

Comment: Indeed, the Dev Guide exactly says that (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ShowingADialog): "If you don't define `onPrepareDialog()`, then the dialog will remain the same as it was the previous time it was opened." Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try using method opposite to showDialog() - removeDialog() is that method. I was having problem similar to yours. Every dialog i was showing was having data from the first instance. When I started to use removeDialog() the content was being updated properly.

Comment: If you call removeDialog, then you are effectively disabling the caching of created dialogs, and you force them to be created again. For performance you should override onPrepareDialog method like I have indicated in my answer.

Comment: Actually, I don't see where I can call removeDialog() (given my context): I assume it should be called right after calling `showDialog(INPUT_TEXT)`, but this never shows the dialog. I'm guessing the dialog runs in its kind of own thread, thus it is already removed even before being shown. I am wrong? Anyway thanks, it drew my attention to this method as well ;-)