# Reset Android DialogFragment

Tags: android

I am using a custom DialogFragment to let a user change his login credentials. There are some text fields and two buttons (save/cancel). The layout is set in DialogFragment's onCreateView method.

If I open the dialog text fields are filled with default values. When the user changes text in a text field and clicks the cancel button the dialog is dismissed. Next time the dialog opens the text field changed before does not contain the default value as i expected but the text the user changed before. The text fields are not reset. This is almost the same problem mentioned here [Reset an Android Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482448/reset-an-android-dialog). The problem is that the solution provided refers to a Dialog which is deprecated in API level 11 and i cannot use onPrepareDialog with a DialogFragment.

Is there a similar way to reset the content of a DialogFragment?

Comment: I have the opposite problem. For some reason I cannot keep the content of the dialog after it is dismissed. Could you explain how you did?

Answer (score 6):

You can override onResume() in your class, which extends DialogFragmet, as follows:

```
private static class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
  public static MyDialogFragment newInstance() {
    // ...
  }

  @Override
  public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Dialog dialog = getDialog();
    // reset code goes here - use dialog as you would have in onPrepareDialog()
  }
}
```

Comment: hi, may I know why onResume is fine but onViewCreated can't even though viewcreated is called ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use .setText() method in Your activity as reaction after negative button click. Eg:
In DialogFragment.java, onCreateDialog(...)define AlertDialog.Builder

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
```

then

```
//this is better than creating button in layout
builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.button_cancel,
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            ((MainAct) getActivity()).cancelDialog(DialogFragment.this);
        }
    }
);
```

In MainActivity.java create method cancelDialog(DialogFragment df) {

```
//here use df to reset text fields
}
```